# Why does adding 3rd party libraries to Angular 8 break the app?

Tags: angular

I am starting a new angular 8 application. I have been adding my own components and building the routing and everything works fine. When I add a 3rd party library, the app no longer renders my content.

First I ran the command line:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Then I imported the material module to the app:

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    ...
],
imports: [
    ...
    MatTableModule,
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Before the above steps my app worked fine. When I run the app now I get:

> Cannot GET /

I know this means there is an issue in the imports but there isn't anything else for me to import for material tables.

The console also does not have any useful information in it.

Suggestions?

Comment: Does the console have error or no? Even if it's not useful it might have some hint of the error. You can also try `ng build` sometimes it shows different error from `ng serve`

Comment: It's hard to say without more information. Have you tried to run an `npm install` and then `ng build` were there any errors in the terminal when you execute these?

Comment: Also, check if you added this `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` to your `style.css` file

Comment: @penleychan ng build led me to the real error. It was in the custom theme scss file that comes with the library

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the material bundle in the scripts in angular.json file. It is auto imported into the bundle, since you are referencing it in the module.

I just did the same (except for importing the script) on a new project and it worked.

Here is a StackBliz example of the solution:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rngvlw

Comment: I removed the scripts import and the app still errors out when I try to run it.

Comment: Just shared stackbliz repo sample

Comment: Thanks for the help but the actual error I was receiving was in the custom.scss file that comes with the library. It had an invalid css line.

Comment: Please add that as a separate answer and accept it, so the question is closed.